# form validation not working in visualforce which working in html

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, jquery-form-validator

Form validation is not working but same code is running in html and form validation also works i have uploaded all static resources please suggest me what changes in code are required.
1. I have uploaded static resourced successfully.
2. All files path is correct.
3. Suggest me if any changes necessary for html tag to visualforce tag

```
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation, 'valid/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation, 'valid/formValidation.min.css')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation,'valid/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.bootstrapjs}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation,'valid/bootstrap1.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation,'valid/formValidation.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.validation,'valid/jquery.min.js')}"/>



    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="basicBootstrapForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
                </div>
                                </div>



                                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Generate a simple captcha
            function randomNumber(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            }
            $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));

            $('#basicBootstrapForm').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    firstName: {
                        row: '.col-xs-4',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The first name is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                 }   

            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this sorted? I'm having similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its an weird issue. It gets resolved when using the CDN like below in HEAD section after Jquery.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```